# No scroll bar with Textarea in processing and controlp5

Tags: java, user-interface, textarea, scrollbar, processing

In the docs for controlp5 it says that a scrollbar will automatically appear when the text exceeds the size of the box, this has not occurred for me, i have also tried `.setScrollActive()` but still no scroll bar, my code is below, thanks in advance..

```
  myTextarea = cp5.addTextarea("listoftweets")
                  .setPosition(500,100)
                  .setSize(200,200)
//                  .setScrollActive(1)
                  .setFont(createFont("arial",12))
                  .setLineHeight(14)
                  .setColor(color(128))
                  .setColorBackground(color(255,100))
                  .setColorForeground(color(255,100));
                  ;

  myTextarea.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
                      +" Quisque sed velit nec eros scelerisque adipiscing vitae eu sem."
                      +" Quisque malesuada interdum lectus. Pellentesque pellentesque molestie"
                      +" vestibulum. Maecenas ultricies, neque at porttitor lacinia, tellus enim"
                      +" suscipit tortor, ut dapibus orci lorem non ipsum. Mauris ut velit velit."
                      +" Fusce at purus in augue semper tincidunt imperdiet sit amet eros."
                      +" Vestibulum nunc diam, fringilla vitae tristique ut, viverra ut felis."
                      +" Proin aliquet turpis ornare leo aliquam dapibus. Integer dui nisi, condimentum"
                      +" ut sagittis non, fringilla vestibulum sapien. Sed ullamcorper libero et massa"
                      +" congue in facilisis mauris lobortis. Fusce cursus risus sit amet leo imperdiet"
                      +" lacinia faucibus turpis tempus. Pellentesque pellentesque augue sed purus varius"
                      +" sed volutpat dui rhoncus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
                    );
```

I also get this warning ...

> 12-Mar-2013 12:42:16 controlP5.ControlP5 checkName WARNING: Controller
>   with name "/listoftweets" already exists. overwriting reference of
>   existing controller.

however i do not have any other controllers with the same name.

Comment: Reduce your code, and then post a minimal running full sketch. Good chance that during your reduction, you actually find the problem, but if it's still there once you've reduced it to a blank sketch with just that single CP5 controller, happy to help figure it out.